# download a web page with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, url, curl

How can i download the html content of a webpage given an url? using objective c..

Answer (score 5):

Use `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` from `NSString`

```
NSURL * url = ... some url
NSError * error;
NSStringEncoding * encoding;
NSString * htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Comment: While this will work, you should never do this from the main thread as it will block until the call returns, which may be a long time if there are network issues. You should either do this on a separate thread or use the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection` instead.

Comment: correct, that you should not do this in the main thread, but with how easy Operation Queues are to use, it would make more sense to use them as opposed to redoing what NSString already does if you want all the contents of the URL.  A good tutorial for Operation Queues is at http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's on iPhone or Mac OS X, use the sample here:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Linking CURL with Objective C might be possible, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to do.  For a web view:

```
webView = [[UIWebview alloc] loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request];
```